# Remote Desktop APP Credentials

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-10, remote-desktop, rdp

I got two remote desktop client applications on my Windows 10 desktop.
I want to execute my .RDP file with windows 10 remote desktop **APP**.

[Its the APP with the red border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyCTr.png)

When i launch te .rdp file its prompts me with a username and password.
But ther is no option to save it. ( in Windows Vault )

[Prompt username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxMth.png)

Normaly i open .rdp files with the the other remote desktop program ( the one without the red border ) and it will prompt me once to save my credentials.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvw4T.png)

Is it possible to save my credentials with te remote destop **APP**

Answer (score 0):

Username is stored in rdp file, what can be edited with notepad.
About password is more security matter than usability. Storing password in file is not safe but can try out [this method](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/867467/rdp-file-with-embedded-password-asks-for-password), but I advise to use specific software as password safe like [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) or any other and configure it to fill all the needed credentials.